# Check for duplicates in particular column after joining two datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add more functionality to my existing code.

This part is responsible for joining two datatables:

```
                var results = from table1 in t2.AsEnumerable()
                              join table2 in t1.AsEnumerable()
                                  on (string)table1["SNAME"] equals (string)table2["SNAME"] into temp
                              from table2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new
                              {
                                  NRO = (string)table1["NRO"],
                                  NRO1 = table2 != null ? (string)table2["NRO"] : string.Empty,
                                  SNAME = (string)table1["SNAME"],
                                  NAMEA = (string)table1["NAMEA"],
                                  NAMEB = (string)table1["NAMEB"],
                                  ADDRESS = (string)table1["ADDRESS"],
                                  POSTS = (string)table1["POSTS"],
                                  POSTNRO = (string)table1["POSTNRO"],
                                  POSTTP = (string)table1["POSTTP"],
                                  COMPANY = (string)table1["COMPANY"],
                                  COUNTRY = (string)table1["COUNTRY"],
                                  BID = (string)table1["BID"]
                              };
```

Now I have tried with below code to check for duplicate records in column `COMPANY` but it says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1929  '' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best
>   extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow,
>   string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'

```
                var duplicates = results.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("COMPANY"))
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
               .Select(g => g.Key)
               .ToList();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone new like I am. While using Visual Studio I highly recommend in case of error delete all parameters to the right and type a dot. Like in this case `dr.Field<string>("COMPANY")` -> remove `.Field<string>("COMPANY")` and Visual Studio will automatically suggest you available parameters, in this case it should be `dr.COMPANY`.

```
var duplicates = results.AsEnumerable()
.Select(dr => dr.COMPANY)
.GroupBy(x => x)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g => g.Key)
.ToList();

duplicates.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
```